# Javascript Worker threads and code reuse

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I have a large Javascript file (approx 10Mb in size), which has a lot of computer intensive processes. I do not have the option of re-factoring the code into smaller files, because its a tightly coupled system.

I don't want to have an unresponsive browser if one of those computationally expensive functions are invoked in a script. I have just read about Javascript workers, and they seem to be the solution to this problem.

However, its not clear if multiple copies of my script will be loaded in each thread, when I invoke:

```
var worker1 = Worker('heavy_lifting_script');
var worker2 = Worker('heavy_lifting_script');
var worker3 = Worker('heavy_lifting_script');
.
.
var workerN = Worker('heavy_lifting_script');
```

I know the browser loads only one copy of a file, no matter how many times it encounters references to it in a file, but it is not clear to me whether this is also the case with Worker threads.

In the pseudo code shown above, will my heavy_lifting_script be loaded N times?. If no why? (or pointer to docs that show why it wil not be loaded N times - would be appreciated).

As an aside, to avoid fielding questions about whether I have minified or compressed the file, I am aware of minification and zipping the file before compression etc. That's not what this question is about. Thank you.

Comment: Your browser will cache the javascript file for you the first time you download it and subsequent calls will load it from the cache. This isn't worker thread specific, your browser will cache any js files.

Comment: @bhspencer: do you have a link that I can use as a reference, if so please post yur comment as an answer, so I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: I don't have a link to docs but there is this other SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124261/chrome-not-loading-latest-version-of-web-worker-script-runs-a-cached-version You could also just try it for your self and see the results.

Comment: The file is only loaded once and cached (unless you send odd headers). Afaik even the parse tree of the JS is cached. But I don't think the (compiled) code itself is shared between the threads, though that is certainly implementation-dependent.