# Shared Worker not being loaded by Chrome (unless in incognito mode)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-worker, shared

**edit**

Renaming the `shared-worker.js` file to anything else, e.g. `shared-worker-new.js`, seems to fix the issue. I have tried emptying the cache, restarting the browser and doing hard-reloads but `shared-worker.js` just doesn't want to work. The *new* worker file doesn't seem to suffer from caching issues. Changes to the file are instantly applied after a reload. Does anyone have any ideas as to why I can't use `shared-worker.js`?

**/edit**

I can't seem to load my Shared Worker in Google Chrome (67.0.3396.99). However when I switch to incognito mode it does work. Firefox (61.0.1) works fine in both regular and private mode. I've already tried disabling my browser plugins but that didn't work either.

I have 3 files (in the same directory): `index.html`, `app.js` and `shared-worker.js`.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Shared Worker Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var worker = new SharedWorker('./shared-worker.js');

worker.port.onmessage = function(message) {
    console.log('message from the shared worker:', message.data);
};

worker.port.start();
worker.port.postMessage('Hello worker');
```

**shared-worker.js**

```
self.onconnect = function(connect) {
    var port = connect.ports[0];

    port.addEventListener('message', function(message) {
        port.postMessage(`I have received "${message.data}"`);
    });

    port.start();
};
```

I am running the app via `php -S localhost:9000`

- In Firefox the console outputs the following: `message from the shared worker: I have received "Hello worker"`.
- In an *incognito* Chrome tab I get the following output: `message from the shared worker: I have received "Hello worker"`.
- In a regular Chrome tab I get no output at all.

I don't see the worker listed under Sources/Threads in the developer tools however when I load the shared-worker as a regular worker, i.e. `var worker = new Worker('shared-worker.js');`, it does appear.

Why can't I load a Shared Worker in chrome, does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Thanks a gazillion in advance!

Comment: Chrome is known to aggressively cache resources such as JS and CSS, so before getting too technical it's worth opening the dev tools, clearing all local storage and performing a hard reload.

Comment: Thank you for your time Widor. I've cleared the cache via Application/Clear storage/Clear site data followed by a hard-reload, but that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: It may be a caching issue after all. I've renamed my `shared-worker` file to `shared-worker-new` and it works. However `shared-worker-new` doesn't seem to be hard cached (changes are applied after a soft refresh). So I am not sure why `shared-worker` wouldn't work. I can't find the worker file anywhere in the developer tools to verify it's a caching issue.

Answer (score 1):

**DOH** - Turns out my devtools were likely to be the cause of the problem ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. It was stopping the execution of my shared worker. If anyone else is running into this problem, make sure you have closed ALL the tabs in the session that use the shared worker and that your debugger is not pausing the execution.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13428856/5744858) fixed it:

> On my Linux Chrome I have to right click (or long click) the reload button and select "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" to get the latest version

If it doesn't work, you can also try this:

1. Settings
2. Privacy and security
3. Clear browsing data
4. Time range: All time
5. Cached images and files: check
6. Clear data

chrome://settings/clearBrowserData

[image: 2]